# Objects are brighter in threejs editor

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I've Imported an FBX object in the editor and it looks as follows:

[image]

Perfect, that what I was expecting!

but when I make my scene and import the same object, it looks like this:

[image]

Waymore darker, but why!

even though am using direct light with the same intensity as both!

these are my editor objects:

[image]

And this is my extra simple code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x9A9A9A );
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.position.z = 5;


var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

//controls.update() must be called after any manual changes to the camera's transform
camera.position.set( 0, 20, 100 );
controls.update();

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
scene.add( directionalLight );
directionalLight.position.set(5,10,8);
var helper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper( directionalLight, 5 );
scene.add( helper );

var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();

loader.load( '/assets/village/village_update.fbx', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        console.info( 'loaded' );
        if (child.isMesh) {
            child.receiveShadow = true;
            child.material.color.set( 0xffffff );
        }
    } );
    object.name = "village";
    console.log( 'adding it to scene' );
    scene.add( object );
});

var animate = function () {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
```

what am I missing here?

Edit:

For anyone who want to inspect the object, you can download it from here:
[object](http://mal-war.com/modules/map/3D/village/village_update.fbx)
[texture](http://mal-war.com/modules/map/3D/village/new_Village_color.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your lights are the same in both scenes, then it looks like an issue of incorrect gamma. Try setting `renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;`, assuming a recent version of three.js. In older versions this would be `renderer.gammaOutput = true;`.

For more details, see [color management in three.js](https://gist.github.com/donmccurdy/fefb35c5ba033e7dcd641f9684e47a82).

three.js r.112

Comment: ok so I have a ground texture that I want to implement to a plane, is that mean I always need to add `material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;` whenever I implement a texture to a material?

Comment: If the texture is used for color data (`.map`, `.emissive`) then yes, for others (e.g. `.normalMap`) stick with `LinearEncoding`. Ideally for PBR you do this for all color textures, and set `renderer.outputEncoding=sRGBEncoding` as shown above ("linear workflow"). An alternative, not as good for PBR but fine for other use cases, is to keep all textures _and_ `outputEncoding` linear ("gamma workflow").  When you mix the two, so the texture settings don't match the renderer settings, you'll have problems like you've run into in this question.

Comment: I needed `outputEncoding = 3000` to fix the color on my project using react fiber

Comment: That's `THREE.LinearEncoding`, and equivalent to the "gamma workflow" mentioned above. It's _usually_ not what you want — unless you are doing gamma correction in post-processing, it suggests something else is not quite set up right. But if it looks good for your project then I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after days of searching and debugging I found this code in FBXLoader:

```
switch ( type ) {

                case 'Bump':
                    parameters.bumpMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    break;

                case 'Maya|TEX_ao_map':
                    parameters.aoMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    break;

                case 'DiffuseColor':
                case 'Maya|TEX_color_map':
                    parameters.map = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    parameters.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                    break;

                case 'DisplacementColor':
                    parameters.displacementMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    break;

                case 'EmissiveColor':
                    parameters.emissiveMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    parameters.emissiveMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                    break;

                case 'NormalMap':
                case 'Maya|TEX_normal_map':
                    parameters.normalMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    break;

                case 'ReflectionColor':
                    parameters.envMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    parameters.envMap.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
                    parameters.envMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                    break;

                case 'SpecularColor':
                    parameters.specularMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    parameters.specularMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                    break;

                case 'TransparentColor':
                    parameters.alphaMap = self.getTexture( textureMap, child.ID );
                    parameters.transparent = true;
                    break;

                case 'AmbientColor':
                case 'ShininessExponent': // AKA glossiness map
                case 'SpecularFactor': // AKA specularLevel
                case 'VectorDisplacementColor': // NOTE: Seems to be a copy of DisplacementColor
                default:
                    console.warn( 'THREE.FBXLoader: %s map is not supported in three.js, skipping texture.', type );
                    break;

            }
```

Which clearly conver the encoding of the texture to `THREE.sRGBEncoding` if `DiffuseColor`.
by console that out I found that the object connection state that the texture is diffused, so it is changing the encoding thus leading to dark shader.

changeing the encooding back to 3000 (normal encoding) and run `material.needUpdates = true` will solve the issue, or simply re export that object correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For me *removing* `renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;` made the images much brighter.